# container started from docker compose is unable to connect to another container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have `docker-compose` that looks like this

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
iam_network:
    external:
    name: foundation_iam
rdc_network:
    name: rdcstu3_net
services:
rdcdeploy:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rdcdeploy
    build:
    context: ./rdcdeploy
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: rdcdeploy:$build_version
    volumes:
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - rdc_network
rdcrabbitmq:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rdcrabbitmq
    build:
    context: ./rabbitmq
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: rdcrabbitmq:$build_version
    ports:
    - "5772:5672"
    - "15772:15672"
    depends_on: 
    - rdcdeploy
    volumes:
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - rdc_network
rdcdb:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rdcdb
    build: 
    context: ./postgres
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: rdcpostgres:$build_version
    ports:
    - "5532:5432"
    depends_on: 
    - rdcdeploy
    volumes: 
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - rdc_network
rdcdbdeploy:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rdcdbdeploy
    build: 
    context: ./rdcdbdeploy
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: rdcdbdeploy:$build_version
    depends_on:
    - rdcdb
    volumes: 
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - rdc_network
rihapp:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rihapp
    build: 
    context: ./rihserver
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: rihapp:$build_version
    ports:
    - "9090:8080"
    depends_on:
    - rdcrabbitmq
    - rdcdb
    volumes: 
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - iam_network
    - rdc_network
subscription_scheduler:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: subscription_scheduler
    build: 
    context: ./subscription
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: subscription_scheduler:$build_version
    depends_on:
    - rdcrabbitmq
    - rdcdb
    - rihapp
    volumes: 
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - iam_network
    - rdc_network
    environment:
    - rdc.subscription.instanceNumber=0
subscription_processor:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: subscription_processor
    build: 
    context: ./subscription
    args: 
        - build_version
        - build_type
    image: subscription_processor:$build_version
    depends_on:
    - rdcrabbitmq
    - rdcdb
    - rihapp
    volumes: 
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    networks:
    - iam_network
    - rdc_network
    environment:
    - rdc.subscription.instanceNumber=1
rdcsmoketest:
    restart: "no"
    container_name: rdcsmoketests
    build:
    context: ./rdcdeploy
    image: rdcdeploy:$build_version
    volumes:
    - ./cfg:/cfg
    depends_on: 
    - rihapp
    networks:
    - iam_network
    - rdc_network
    entrypoint:
    - wait-for-rihapp.sh
    - rdcdeploy
    command: ["-x", "-z", "/cfg", "-c", "/cfg/config.yml", "docker"]
```

I start it using `docker-compose up` and it shows that the containers are started.

```
eedaa5e11a0e        rdicdeploy:3.3.0.1                "wait-for-rihapp.sh…"   2 minutes ago       Up 38 seconds                                                                                                    rdicsmoketests
9178355cbca7        subscription_scheduler:3.3.0.1   "./wait-for-env.sh /…"   2 minutes ago       Up 38 seconds                                                                                                    subscription_scheduler
ae24a4b76f3e        subscription_processor:3.3.0.1   "./wait-for-env.sh /…"   2 minutes ago       Up 38 seconds                                                                                                    subscription_processor
5f789ae74ef2        rihapp:3.3.0.1                  "./wait_for_rdic_db.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 39 seconds       0.0.0.0:9090->8080/tcp                                                                       rihapp
698b26d0ca37        rdicdbdeploy:3.3.0.1              "wait-for-env-db.sh …"   2 minutes ago       Up 39 seconds                                                                                                    rdicdbdeploy
592cb850f5b9        rdicrabbitmq:3.3.0.1              "wait-for-env.sh /cf…"   2 minutes ago       Up 39 seconds       4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5772->5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15772->15672/tcp   rdicrabbitmq
505a0f36528f        rdicpostgres:3.3.0.1              "wait-for-env.sh /cf…"   2 minutes ago       Up 39 seconds       0.0.0.0:5532->5432/tcp
```

But for some reason no container are able to connect either rabbitmq or postgres.

Logs for `rabbitmq` shows that they have started

```
2020-07-24 10:32:13.226 [info] <0.370.0> Running boot step direct_client defined by app rabbit
2020-07-24 10:32:13.226 [info] <0.370.0> Running boot step os_signal_handler defined by app rabbit
2020-07-24 10:32:13.226 [info] <0.489.0> Swapping OS signal event handler (erl_signal_server) for our own
2020-07-24 10:32:13.262 [info] <0.539.0> Management plugin: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15672
2020-07-24 10:32:13.262 [info] <0.645.0> Statistics database started.
2020-07-24 10:32:13.262 [info] <0.644.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
2020-07-24 10:32:13.480 [info] <0.8.0> Server startup complete; 3 plugins started.
* rabbitmq_management
* rabbitmq_web_dispatch
* rabbitmq_management_agent
completed with 3 plugins.
```

For `postgres` too

```
server started
CREATE DATABASE

CREATE ROLE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down...LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.LOG:  aborting any active transactions
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-07-24 10:30:59 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
Environment Available - proceeding with startup docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-07-24 10:31:00 UTC
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  invalid record length at 0/14EEEA0: wanted 24, got 0
LOG:  redo is not required
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

But the applications are trying to connect `5772` but the connection refused for rabbitmq and for `postgres` it also tells that

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused

rihapp                   |     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
rihapp                   |     TCP/IP connections on port 5532?
```

It also generates `.env` files that contains environment variables for APPS like

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://rdc:rdc@localhost:5532/pg_db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5532/pg_db
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5772
```

What might be a problem? It feels like some kind of network problem.

Comment: `localhost` in Docker almost always means "this container".  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the network environment and how to connect between containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've configured the clients to contact the servers on `localhost:X`, am I getting this right?

In that case you need to be aware that containers in docker-compose have different network cgroups, and are able to reach each other through a bridge interface. This means that in the container, you should use `rdcrabbitmq:5672` instead of `localhost:5772`

Comment: Yes, I set host to localhost

Comment: @lapots in that case, the clients from a container should reach the services in the service's name, such as `rdcrabbitmq:5672` or `rcdb:5432`

Comment: so I should set them to the value o container_name in docker-compose?

Comment: I'd use the name of their service block, and remove the `container_name:` options.

Comment: what port should I use? in `env` file it uses `jdbc:postgresql://rdcdb:5532/pg_db` but still cannot to connect. While I was able to connect externally using `0.0.0.0:5532`

Comment: @lapots if you connect from a container, you should use the port where the service is listening (In PG I think it's 5432), docker-compose's `ports: ["5532:5432"]` happens in another level